# Vim の Syntasticがうまく動作しない

Tags: vim

Vimでjavascriptのシンタックスチェックをしたくて、[scrooloose/syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)を導入したのですが、正しく動作しません。
以下の画像のように`:SyntasticInfo javascript`でチェックすると、`Available checkers`も`Current enabled checkers`も空になってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

jshintはnpmでインストールし、パスは以下のようになっています。

```
$ which jshint
/Users/***/.nodebrew/current/bin/jshint
```

また、.vimrcは以下のように設定をしています。

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = {
  \ 'mode': 'active',
  \ 'active_filetypes': ['javascript'],
  \ 'passive_filetypes': ['html']
  \}
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_javascript_jshint_exec='/Users/***/.nodebrew/current/bin/jshint'
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']
```

`syntastic_javascript_jshint_exec`に関しては、jshintのパスが通っていれば、設定不要であるという認識ですが、以下を参照して、一応設定しています。
[Syntastic doesn't detect JSHint as an available checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661653/syntastic-doesnt-detect-jshint-as-an-available-checker)

なにか、情報をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimのパスの問題でした。
`:echo $PATH`でパスを確認したところ、jshintのパスが設定されていませんでした。
以下を参考にzshのPATHを`.zshenv`に設定したところ正しく動作しました。
[why $PATH in vim and in zsh is different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548351/why-path-in-vim-and-in-zsh-is-different)

また、原因はわかりませんが、Neobundleでインストールしたsyntasticのバージョンが最新の3.6ではなかったので、`:NeoBundleClean`をしてから再インストールしました。

Comment: ちなみに質問とは無関係ですが，neobundle には `:NeoBundleReinstall` というコマンドも定義されています．

Comment: @Yosh なるほど〜、 `:NeoBundleReinstall syntastic`で再インストールできるんですね！